# cannot import scrapy modules as library

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to run spiders from python script following scrapy document: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

spider = FollowAllSpider(domain='scrapinghub.com')
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the spider_closed signal was sent
```

But python just cannot import the module, the error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
  File "aappp/scrapy.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named crawler
```

The issue is briefly mentioned in faq of scrapy document, but it doesn't help too much for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it this way?

```
from scrapy.project import crawler
```

(That's how it's done on http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html - looks like they already answered your question there.)

It also gives a more recent way of doing it and calls this previous method deprecated:

"This way to access the crawler object is deprecated, the code should be ported to use from_crawler class method, for example:

class SomeExtension(object):

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    o = cls()
    o.crawler = crawler
    return o
```

"

Comment: it doesn't work: In [1]: from scrapy.project import crawler
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ubuntu/src/<ipython-input-1-4129a70e7e35> in <module>()
----> 1 from scrapy.project import crawler

ImportError: cannot import name crawler

In [2]: import scrapy

In [3]: scrapy.__version__
Out[3]: '0.18.4'